# Ruby on Rails rake test:units error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rake, units-of-measurement

I have a problem about product_text.rb

I'm newbie in RoR, this example is from Agile Web Development from Sam Ruby and Dave Thomas.

my product_test.rb looks like this

```
#---
# Excerpted from "Agile Web Development with Rails",
# published by The Pragmatic Bookshelf.
# Copyrights apply to this code. It may not be used to create training material, 
# courses, books, articles, and the like. Contact us if you are in doubt.
# We make no guarantees that this code is fit for any purpose. 
# Visit http://www.pragmaticprogrammer.com/titles/rails4 for more book information.
#---
#---
# Excerpted from "Agile Web Development with Rails, 4rd Ed.",
# published by The Pragmatic Bookshelf.
# Copyrights apply to this code. It may not be used to create training material, 
# courses, books, articles, and the like. Contact us if you are in doubt.
# We make no guarantees that this code is fit for any purpose. 
# Visit http://www.pragmaticprogrammer.com/titles/rails4 for more book information.
#---
require 'test_helper'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "product attributes must not be empty" do
    product = Product.new
    assert product.invalid?
    assert product.errors[:title].any?
    assert product.errors[:description].any?
    assert product.errors[:price].any?
    assert product.errors[:image_url].any?
  end

  test "product price must be positive" do
    product = Product.new(:title       => "My Book Title",
                          :description => "yyy",
                          :image_url   => "zzz.jpg")
    product.price = -1
    assert product.invalid?
    assert_equal "must be greater than or equal to 0.01", 
      product.errors[:price].join('; ')

    product.price = 0
    assert product.invalid?
    assert_equal "must be greater than or equal to 0.01", 
      product.errors[:price].join('; ')

    product.price = 1
    assert product.valid?
  end

  def new_product(image_url)
    Product.new(:title       => "My Book Title",
                :description => "yyy",
                :price       => 1,
                :image_url   => image_url)
  end

  test "image url" do
    ok = %w{ fred.gif fred.jpg fred.png FRED.JPG FRED.Jpg
             http://a.b.c/x/y/z/fred.gif }
    bad = %w{ fred.doc fred.gif/more fred.gif.more }

    ok.each do |name|
      assert new_product(name).valid?, "#{name} shouldn't be invalid"
    end

    bad.each do |name|
      assert new_product(name).invalid?, "#{name} shouldn't be valid"
    end
  end

  test "product is not valid without a unique title" do
    product = Product.new(:title       => products(:ruby).title,
                          :description => "yyy", 
                          :price       => 1, 
                          :image_url   => "fred.gif")

    assert !product.save
    assert_equal "has already been taken", product.errors[:title].join('; ')
  end

  test "product is not valid without a unique title - i18n" do
    product = Product.new(:title       => products(:ruby).title,
                          :description => "yyy", 
                          :price       => 1, 
                          :image_url   => "fred.gif")

    assert !product.save
    assert_equal I18n.translate('activerecord.errors.messages.taken'),
                 product.errors[:title].join('; ')
  end

end
```

and the output from the console:

```
juldou-programming@juldou-programming-laptop:~/work/depot$ rake --trace  test:units
(in /home/juldou-programming/work/depot)
** Invoke test:units (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:load
** Execute test:prepare
** Execute test:units
Loaded suite /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
..EE.
Finished in 0.075767 seconds.

  1) Error:
test_product_is_not_valid_without_a_unique_title(ProductTest):
StandardError: No fixture with name 'ruby' found for table 'products'
    /test/unit/product_test.rb:69:in `test_product_is_not_valid_without_a_unique_title'

  2) Error:
test_product_is_not_valid_without_a_unique_title_-_i18n(ProductTest):
StandardError: No fixture with name 'ruby' found for table 'products'
    /test/unit/product_test.rb:79:in `test_product_is_not_valid_without_a_unique_title_-_i18n'

5 tests, 19 assertions, 0 failures, 2 errors
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/bin/ruby1.8 -I"lib:test" "/usr/lib/ru...]
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:995
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1010:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1010:in `sh'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1094:in `sh'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1029:in `ruby'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1094:in `ruby'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:26
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1112:in `verbose'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:11
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Thank you

Comment: You probably need to read again how to set up fixtures.

Comment: which line is line 79?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed this in products.yml

```
ruby:
    title: Programming Ruby 1.9 
    description:
        Ruby is the fastest growing and most exciting dynamic language out there. 
        If you need to get working programs delivered fast, you should add Ruby to 
        your toolbox.
    price: 49.50
    image_url: ruby.jpg
```